# Unexpectedly large array created with numpy.ones when setting names

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to get a `10 x 8 array` using the code below with numpy

```
import numpy as np
columns = ["Port Wt", "Bench Wt", "Port Retn", 
               "Bench Retn", "Attrib", "Select", "Inter", "Total"]
a = np.ones([10,len(columns)], 
               dtype={"names":columns, "formats":["f8"]*len(columns)})
```

I'm new to numpy and I get unexpected behaviour - I'm getting a `10 x 8 x 8 grid` instead.

I've tried

```
a.dtype.names = columns
```

and get a `ValueError: there are no fields defined`

What am I doing wrong and how would I get a 10 x 8 grid as desired with the names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does produce a `10 x 8` array, i.e. `a.shape == (10, 8)`. However, each element in the array has 8 fields, adding to a total of `10 x 8 x 8` fields.

So what you probably want is an array with shape `(10,)` and 8 fields per element:

```
a = np.ones((10,), dtype={"names":columns, "formats":["f8"]*len(columns)})
```